# c# 7.2 default expression and Equals (bug?)

Tags: c#, default, valuetuple, c#-7.2

I'm using Visual Studion 2017 version 15.5.2, and C# version 7.2. To the point:

```
Color c = default;                              // or: c = default(Color); no difference
Debug.Print($"{c.Equals(default(Color))}");     // true
Debug.Print($"{c.Equals(default)}");            // false WHY?!
```

But if I use ValueTuple:

```
(string s, int i) t = default;                  
Debug.Print($"{t.Equals(default((string, int)))}"); // true
Debug.Print($"{t.Equals(default)}");                // true
```

Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: The results look fine to me, which bit is confusing you?

Comment: Wasn't default part of 7.1?

Comment: I guess `default` in `c.Equals(default)` is `default(object)` and not `default(Color)` since the `Equals` methods is expecting `object` and not `Color`.

Comment: @fharreau Then `t.Equals(default)` should be `false` as well, no?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Exactly!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Looks like `Equals` for tuples has an override, I assume it compares the values of the tuple?

Comment: I guess not because `Color` is a Struct, so a value type, when `Tuple` is a Reference type ...

Comment: Is it `System.Drawing.Color` which is a struct?

Comment: @fharreau `ValueTuple` is a structure as well.  The difference is that it defines an `Equals` that takes a `ValueTuple` and `Color` does not define an `Equals` that takes a `Color`

Comment: @fharreau ValueTuple is also a struct; both are struct so this bevahiour seem inconsistent to me.

Comment: @lisz it has nothing to do with what type they are, it has to do with the `Equals()` method and how its implemented in each

Comment: @maccettura I get it now, thanks guys :) A bit tricky this is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this Windows Forms?

Because in WinForms, `System.Drawing.Color.Equals()` doesn't have an overload that takes a `Color`. Instead, it only has [the one from `Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2.aspx). In WPF, `System.Windows.Media.Color.Equals()` contains an overload that [takes a `Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606545.aspx).

When `default` is passed as an argument to `Color.Equals(Object)`, what gets passed is `default(Object)` since the compiler infers `Object` to be the type based on its signature. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference):

> The `default` literal produces the same value as the equivalent `default(T)` where `T` is the inferred type.

Clearly, `default(Color)` isn't equivalent to `default(Object)`, since `Color` is a value type and `Object` is a reference type (which defaults to null).

`ValueTuple.Equals()`, on the other hand, [takes another `ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791165.aspx), so the compiler has no trouble inferring the type of `default` as `default(ValueTuple)`.

Edit:

As of .NET Core 2.0, `System.Drawing.Color.Equals()` does have an overload that takes a `Color`. The compiler would have no trouble inferring the type of default as default(Color); therefore, it would now return true.

Comment: I was wrong about what "default expression" realy means. This is clear for me now, thanks.

Comment: @lisz Like lambda expressions, `default` is one of the few cases in C# where type information flows from the type of the assignment target to the type of the thing being assigned.  In your example, the assignment target is a method parameter, so the type information comes from there.

Comment: @Mike Strobel I got confused, because I somehow thought c.Equals(default) should be equivalent to "c == default" (where c is System.Drawing.Color) - but they are completely different things.

Answer (score 5):

@fharreau is correct: `System.Drawing.Color` does not implement an `Equals(Color)` method, so `$"{t.Equals(default)}"` binds to the only method available: `Equals(Object)`.  Thus, `default` resolves to `default(Object)` or `null`.

If you use `System.Windows.Media.Color` from WPF, which *does* implement `Equals(Color)`, then you'll see the expected results:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color c = default;
Console.WriteLine($"{c.Equals(default(System.Windows.Media.Color))}");  // true
Console.WriteLine($"{c.Equals(default)}");                              // true
```

`ValueTuple` also provides an `Equals` to compare against another tuple, which is why you saw the expected result.

Answer (score 5):

In the first code block, the `.Equals()` method comes from the base `object` class, meaning the `default` will be the default value for `object` and not `Color`. This is why it returns false.

The tuple `.Equals()` method however has been overriden to take the relevant type, the internals of that function compare the individual components. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791195(v=vs.110).aspx), a ValueTuple is considered equal if:

> - Its components are of the same types as those of the current instance.
> - Its components are equal to those of the current instance. Equality is determined by the default equality comparer for each component.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is as expected.

`default` provides the default value for the type of parameter or variable or whatnot it is assigned to.

So let's look at this:

```
Color c = Color.White;
bool b = c.Equals(x);
```

What type is `x` expected to be? since the `Color` type does not declare a `Equals` method that takes `Color`, the only method available is this:

```
public class Object
{
    public virtual bool Equals(object obj)
    ...
```

So the `default` here will be expected to fulfill the need of `object`, not `Color`, hence your code is actually this:

```
bool b = c.Equals(default(object));
```

which is the same as this:

```
bool b = c.Equals(null);
```

But hang on, why then is this true?

```
bool b = c.Equals(default(Color));
```

? That is because `Color` *overrides* the `Equals` method from `object`, **or** the base method knows how to compare value types, that still takes `object` as parameter, and thus your other statement:

```
bool b = c.Equals(default(Color));
```

actually provides a `Color`, and not `null`, and that's why the two are different.

Answer (score 3):

This result matches the documentation, but the documentation for the second (Tuple) snippet doesn't say what you might expect.

The [Color.Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2(v=vs.110).aspx) method accepts an argument of type `Object`. So you're comparing the default color to the default Object. Those are not the same, hence the `false` result.

[ValueType.Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple.equals(v=vs.110).aspx) has overloads to accept arguments for both `Object` and `ValueTuple`. The documentation here is interesting... *the version with the ValueTuple argument always returns true*. The Object version returns true if the argument is a ValueTuple, or false otherwise. In other words, according to the Equals method, all ValueTuples are equal to each other, but not equal to anything that isn't a ValueTuple.

The only other trick here is how the `default` keyword is interpreted in this context. We can clearly see here that you're getting a default ValueTuple, rather than a default Object. I'm not up to date on exactly *why* or *how* the compiler is able to determine this from the context, but once you have that value for the argument it's easy to see why you get the `true` result in this case. Clearly overload resolution would then choose the ValueTuple of the method, which (again) always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Drawing.Color` structure does not implement `IEquatable` whereas `ValueTuple` does.

So in first case compiler selects `Object.Equals`

Comment: IEquatable is irrelevant. He's calling .Equals() explicitly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Have you ever met struct with `Equals(T other)`, which did not implement `IEquatable<T>`?

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't implement IEquatable<T>. I said it's irrelevant whether it does or not, because the code in the question is calling .Equals() directly, and types are able to overload Equals() method without implementing IEquatable.